# program using class point class circle java

Tags: java

Create class Point which has two private members: int x and int y, representing point's coordinates. Class Point has two constructors:

1. Point() that assigns zeros to variables x and y, and
2. Point(int x, int y) that assigns values x and y to variables this.x and this.y, respectively.

Also, write a member method public void move(int x, int y) which assigns values x and y to private members and override method public String toString() which returns String representation of a Point (x + " " + y).

Create class Circle which has two private members: int radius and Point center. Write the following counstructors:

1. Circle() - assume that default radius is 1 and center (0,0)
2. Circle(int radius) - that assigns integer radius to this.radius (center at 0,0)
3. Circle(Point center) - that assigns point center to this.center (radius 1)
4. Circle(int radius, Point center) - that assigns integer radius to this.radius and point center to this.center

Also, write the following member methods:

1. double area() - which computes the circle's area
2. double circumference() - which computes the circle's circumference
3. String toString() - which returns String representation of circle's radius and center.

Write a driver class Lab2.java which instantiates several objects of type Point and Circle (at least 4, using 4 different constructors) and tests all your member methods.

```
class Point {

    private int x; 
    private int y;

    public Point(){
        x = y = 0; 
    }

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
    }

    public void move (int x, int y){
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "x: " + x + "y: " + y; 
        return s; 
    }
}

class Circle{
    private int radius; 
    private Point center; 

    public Circle(){
        int radius = 1; 
        Point center = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public Circle(int radius){ 
        int radius = this.radius(center(0,0));  
    }

    public Circle(Point center){ 
        Point center = this.center(radius (1));   
    } 

    public Circle(int radius, Point center){
        int radius = this.radius; 
        Point center = this.center; 
    }

    double area() {
        return Math.PI*radius*radius; 
    }

    double circumference(){
        return 2*Math.PI*radius; 
    }

    String toString( ){
        String s = "radius: " + radius + "center: " + center; 
        return s; 
    }
}

class Lab21{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Circle c = new Circle (); 
        System.out.println(c); 
        c.move(4,2); 
        System.out.println(c); 
        c.resize(5,2); 
        System.out.println(c); 

        point center = new Point(3,3); 
        Circle s = new Circle (6, 1, center); 
        System.out.println(s); 
    }
}
```

These are the errors I'm currently getting:

```
Lab21.java:37: error: variable radius is already defined in constructor Circle(int)
    int radius = this.radius(center(0,0));  
        ^
Lab21.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    int radius = this.radius(center(0,0));  
                             ^
  symbol:   method center(int,int)
  location: class Circle
Lab21.java:41: error: variable center is already defined in constructor Circle(Point)
    Point center = this.center(radius (1));   
          ^
Lab21.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    Point center = this.center(radius (1));   
                               ^
  symbol:   method radius(int)
  location: class Circle
Lab21.java:45: error: variable radius is already defined in constructor Circle(int,Point)
    int radius = this.radius; 
        ^
Lab21.java:46: error: variable center is already defined in constructor Circle(int,Point)
    Point center = this.center; 
          ^
Lab21.java:57: error: toString() in Circle cannot override toString() in Object
String toString(){
       ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
Lab21.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    r.move(4,2); 
    ^
  symbol:   variable r
  location: class Lab21
Lab21.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
    r.resize(5,2); 
    ^
  symbol:   variable r
  location: class Lab21
Lab21.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
    point center = new Point(3,3); 
    ^
  symbol:   class point
  location: class Lab21
```

Comment: -- with all due respect, shouldn't you be showing us your code attempt first? Then if that  doesn't work, shouldn't you be asking us a specific and answerable question and not simply dumping your assignment requirements on this site? Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I am doing it, as you can see in my edit....... but I was getting so many errors I didn't see any point in actually posting it

Comment: Post what errors you're getting and we'll be happy to take a look for you.

Comment: I got you. You were doing fine in the Point class, but seem to get really confused in the Circle class. Ask if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: got it running now. just working on the four circles now. Thanks!

Comment: @mmking could you take a look??

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes were mostly in your Circle class. I think you need a few clarifiations:

1. The properties `radius` and `center` are already declared in the beginning of your class. You should not declare them again in the constructor. Declaring a variable means specifying what type it is, like `int radius` or `Point center`.
2. If you call `radius(1)`, java thinks you are looking for a method called radius and passing in value of 1 to it. But you didn't define a method called radius or center. `center` is just a point and `radius` is just an integer.

To assign values to them, you need to do something like

```
this.radius = 1;
this.center = new Point(0, 0);
```

This says, assign a value of 1 to the radius of this circle and assign a new Point at (0,0) as the center of this circle.

3. In your constructor, you want to assign values to your properties. Your properties can be accessed by calling `this.radius`, which means, the radius of the current instance of Circle. What you seem to be doing is assigning a value to a new variable called `radius`.

So the default constructor should look like this:

```
public Circle(){
    this.radius = 1; 
    this.center = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

You tell it to set radius of this circle to value 1 and the center of this circle to be a point at (0,0).

The other constructors are defined similarly. For example, the constructor where you specify the radius and the center should look like this:

```
public Circle(int radius, Point center){
    this.radius = radius; 
    this.center = center; 
}
```

This says, set the radius of this circle to be the radius I specified when I called the method and the center of this circle to be the center I specified.

---

This is what it should look like:

```
class Circle {
    private int radius; 
    private Point center; 

    public Circle(){
        this.radius = 1; 
        this.center = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public Circle(int radius){ 
        this.radius = radius;
        this.center = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public Circle(Point center){ 
        this.radius = 1;
        this.center = center;   
    } 

    public Circle(int radius, Point center){
        this.radius = radius; 
        this.center = center; 
    }

    double area() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius; 
    }

    double circumference(){
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius; 
    }

    public String toString( ){
        String s = "radius: " + radius + "center: " + center; 
        return s; 
    }
}
```

---

And there's some small mistakes in your main method.

**First,**

```
point center = new Point(3,3);
```

should be

```
Point center = new Point(3, 3);
```

If you wrote it like that, java goes off and tries to find a class called `point` and then complains because it can't find it. You need to tell it to look for `Point`, with a capital P.

**Second,**

```
Circle s = new Circle (6, 1, center);
```

should be something like

```
Circle s = new Circle (6, center);
```

You don't have a constructor that takes three arguments. You can only specify one value for radius and one for center.

**Finally,** you can't call

```
c.move(4,2);
c.resize(5,2);
```

The first method is for objects of type Point. You can't tell a Circle to act like a Point. The second method isn't even defined.

Comment: Your assignment asked for a demonstration of all four constructors. You can do that by yourself. Create four different circles, one using each constructor, and print them out.